# Speed up my Javascript Scroll-Event Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, scroll

I added some special features to the sidebar of my webapplication. You can see a concept of the user interface on my [testing site](http://services.asdevo.de/). (It's about the right sidebar)

1. The sidebar stops scrolling if it is scrolled to its end.
2. Moreover there are selected listitems in the sidebar wich stay on the top or the bottom of the sidebar if they would scroll out of the view.

My code is written in Javascript using jQuery. Unfortunately scrolling on my page is lagging now. Here are the links to my [demo page](http://services.asdevo.de/) (rightclick -> show sourcecode) and its [javascript file](http://services.asdevo.de/js/scroll.js).

**How can I speed up the code** (and let is still abstract) **?**

I paste the javascript code here for those of you who don't want to follow the links.

HTML: (example)

```
<ul id="right">
    <li><h3>Headline</h3></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a class="selected">Active Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><h3>Headline</h3></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
    <li><a>Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
var Scrollers = $('#content,#left,#right');
var Scrollable = new Array(Scrollers.length);
var TopOffset = new Array(Scrollers.length);
var BottomOffset = new Array(Scrollers.length);
var OuterHeight = new Array(Scrollers.length);
var OuterHeightAndOffsets = new Array(Scrollers.length);
function ScrollInit(){

    Scrollers.each(function(i){

        // constants
        TopOffset[i] = parseInt($(this).css("margin-top").replace("px",""));
        BottomOffset[i] = parseInt($(this).css("margin-bottom").replace("px",""));
        OuterHeight[i] = parseInt($(this).outerHeight());
        OuterHeightAndOffsets[i] = TopOffset[i] + BottomOffset[i] + OuterHeight[i];

        // classes
        $(this).removeClass('snapped top bottom');

        if(OuterHeightAndOffsets[i] < $(window).height()){
            $(this).addClass('snapped top');
            Scrollable[i] = false;
        } else {
            Scrollable[i] = true;
        }
    });
}
ScrollInit();


var SelectedListitems = $('li.selected');
var SelectedListitemsActive = new Array(SelectedListitems.length); for(var i=SelectedListitems.length; i<0; i++) SelectedListitemsActive[i] = false;
function ScrollCalc(){

    // list item locking
    SelectedListitems.each(function(i){
        if(!($(this).parent().hasClass('snapped top'))){
            var ListItemOffset = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
            var ListItemState=0; // 0:in, 1:above, 2:under
            if(ListItemOffset <= $(this).parent().offset().top){ ListItemState=1; }
            else if(ListItemOffset + $(this).outerHeight() >= $(window).height()){ ListItemState=2; }

            // no snapped clone so far
            if(ListItemState){
                if(SelectedListitemsActive[i]!=true && !$(this).parent().hasClass('snapped')){
                    var AppendClasses = 'clone snapped '; if(ListItemState == 1) AppendClasses += 'top '; else AppendClasses += 'bottom ';
                    $(this).parent().append($(this).clone().addClass(AppendClasses + i));
                    SelectedListitemsActive[i] = true;
                }
            // already snapped, clone existing
            } else {
                if(SelectedListitemsActive[i]==true){
                    $('.clone.snapped.' + i).remove();
                    SelectedListitemsActive[i] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // scroll container locking
    Scrollers.each(function(i){
        if(Scrollable[i]){
            if($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height() > OuterHeightAndOffsets[i]){
                $(this).addClass('snapped bottom');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('snapped bottom');
            }
        }
    });

    ScrollEvent = false;
}
ScrollCalc();

$(window).scroll(function(){
    ScrollCalc();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just have a look at you link and believe that the **lagging is not because of your javascript**. If you don't think so try to disable all scripts in window.scroll event, still lagging right?

Now try to remove all shadow properties - box-shadow and text-shadow. Also remember to disable changing shadow opacity in simple.js (changing shadow during scroll event always laggy).

Now you can see it run very fast!!! Back to css file and enable each shadow properties and find out what is most suitable for you.

Comment: Your right, it is very smooth without `box-shadow`s. By the way only changing shadow opacity in simple.js isn't laggy. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

There is a much faster, easier way to get the effect you want.

Try this: when the window scrolls down far enough, set your sidebar's css `position` property to `fixed`. When it scrolls up, set the `position` of the sidebar back to `relative`.

---

var sidebar = document.getElementById('side'),
    section;

sidebar.style.position = 'relative';
sidebar.style.bottom = '0px';
sidebar.style.right = '0px';

```
window.onscroll = function(){
    var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop,
        maxTop = section ? section.offsetTop : sidebar.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight;
    sidebar.style.top = sidebar.style.bottom = null;
    if (scrollTop > maxTop) {
        if (section) {
            sidebar.style.top = - section.offsetTop + 'px';
        } else {
            sidebar.style.bottom = '0px';
        }
        sidebar.style.position = 'fixed';
    } else {
        sidebar.style.position = 'relative';
    }
}
```

---

You can see it working here - http://jsfiddle.net/cL4Dy/

Comment: Locking the sidebar is only the first feature. Your fiddle don't work for me but my solution was nearly the same. Instead editing properties I added classes (`snapped bottom`). Please look at the block `// scroll container locking` in my JS code. Maybe it takes a lot of time adding/removing classes?

Comment: I edited my code to work in more browsers ;) I'll take a look at the second part in a minute.

Comment: @sharethis alright, edited to account for the selected side items (click the headers to select them [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cL4Dy/))

Comment: Thanks, your fiddle works for me now (first part) and it is very quick. I think changing single properties is faster than toggeling css classes.

Comment: I want to hold only the selected entries but not the hole sidebar. Furthermore it doesn't works if the entry get out of view on the bottom.

Comment: Let me look at your example again, hang on.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see any change.

Comment: Yes it is. But read Bui Coung's answer. He was totaly right. Thanks for you effort you get an upvote. My problem is solved.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even notice the box shadows... yeah unfortunately those are slow too :(